# Uncomment java code in eclipse shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse

I comment my java code multiple lines by using shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. Then it will look like this :

```
 /*
 * System.out.println("shree"); test123 t = new test123();
 * 
 * int result = t.Mult(5, 5); System.out.println(result);
 */
```

But when I try to uncomment it, it is looking like this. To uncomment it I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

```
 * System.out.println("shree"); test123 t = new test123();
 * 
 * int result = t.Mult(5, 5); System.out.println(result);
```

My question is, when I used a shortcut to uncomment my java code for multiple line then a initial `/*` and end `*/` will go but the `*` (asterix sign) before every line will not go. I have to remove it manually and that is time consuming.

So there is any shortcut which will give me a solution and will save my time.

Comment: u can use ctrl + / - to comment and same for uncomment.

Comment: Thanks its working,but i would also like to know shortcut for above problem,

Comment: Could be an issue with the particular version of Eclipse you are using. Maybe if you share what version that is, it might help.

Comment: i am using Eclipse LUNA
version=4.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of commenting like `/* some commented code */`, you could use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> which comments/uncomments each of the selected lines separately using `//`

I'm currently on Eclipse Mars, but it used to work this way in Luna as well.